# Как создать личный сайт-портфолио на React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, cms, backend

кто читает.
Передо мной задача: хочу создать личный сайт, где будет возможность вносить изменения. То есть, насколько я понимаю — динамический сайт.

Вопрос 1:
**Небольшое отступление: CRUD todo app на React можно считать как-то связанным с CMS? 
Если в самом приложении есть возможность вносить изменения и редактировать содержимое, это CMS?**

Окей, перехожу к следующему:
У меня есть опыт с React, Mobx, firebase. Пробовал делать приложение и с написанием серверной части, с использованием MongoDB, graphql, Apollo. Немного помогло разобраться как это работает. 
Но теперь всплыло много вопросов, насчёт того, как я могу реализовать свой сайт.

На этом сайте я хочу предоставить информацию о себе, то есть, это будет находиться на главной титульной странице. Там же и будет раздел со ссылками на мои роды деятельности. Естественно, буду юзать роутинг.
Так вот, на такие деятельности, возьму на пример Фронтенд Разработка, я хочу добавить возможность расширять и редактировать своё портфолио: создать новый проект, редактировать существующий и т.д. То есть, принцип CRUD.
В случае с другой деятельность, фотографией, история та же самая: создать новый альбом/подборку, задать ей название и описание, и т.д.

Вопрос 2: 
**Чтобы мне сделать такой функционал, грубо говоря, могу я использовать тот же принцип, что и при создании CRUD todo приложения? Или же, мне нужно какая-то CMS, админка, где я смогу редактировать содержимое сайта?**

Естественно, зачем мне такой функционал. Ну во первых, чтобы каждый раз в код ручками не лезть для внесения изменений на сайт. Ну а во вторых, сайт не будет ограничиваться главной страницей и портфолио с описанием из каждой деятельности.

В планах у меня есть сделать функционал шире. Хочу добавить блог. На этом пока остановлюсь.

Вопрос 3:
**Какие есть готовые/хорошие решения для такой задачи? Что мне лучше делать?**

Да, слышал я о инструментах как **Gatsby**, **Strapi**.
Подходят ли они мне, стоит ли с ними разобраться и их использовать?

Да, насколько я понимаю, естественно для этого всего нужна будет база данных, чтобы хранить инфу. И фотки будут же храниться там. Хочу использовать firebase.

Вопрос 4:
**Что посоветуете, правильно ли я вообще понимаю CMS, правильно ли подхожу к задаче?**

Очень хочу создать личный сайт.
Спасибо, буду рад помощи.

Comment: Конкретизируйте свои вопросы на один вопрос.Так никто на него не ответит его просто закроют.